# Creating log file if CPU percentage is over 25%

Tags: powershell

I'm currently trying to get the results of

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor | select SystemName, LoadPercentage
```

to create a log file if the load percentage is 25% or greater.

Comment: Do you mean `... | Where-Object { $_.LoadPercentage -gt 25 } | Export-Csv C:\path\to\output.csv -NoType`?

Comment: That works wonderfully. I just started learning Powershell less than 48 hours ago and this one was a complete mystery. Also, if I wanted this script to run every 15 minutes, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To record CPU load >25% every 15 minutes I'd use a script like this:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor |
  Where-Object { $_.LoadPercentage -gt 25 } |
  Select-Object @{n='Timestamp';e={(Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')}},
                SystemName, LoadPercentage |
  Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv' -NoType -Append
```

and run it as a scheduled task every 15 minutes.

Note that you need PowerShell v3 or newer to be able to use `Export-Csv -Append`. On older versions you can work around the limitation like this:

```
... | ConvertTo-Csv -NoType |
  Select-Object -Skip 1 |
  Add-Content 'C:\path\to\output.csv'
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much for the guidance.